# Why is the article not present in the phrase *el cepillo de dientes*

Tags: gramática, artículos

Why do we say

> el cepillo del pelo

but

> el cepillo **de** dientes

rather than

> el cepillo **de los** dientes

Comment: We don't say "cepillo del pelo" because that would mean that hair has a brush. If you say cepillo del coche or cepillo de la cocina, those would be brushes that belong to the car and kitchen respectively. That are used in those places and not others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Cepillo de dientes* is a recognizable, often-used expression that points to a specific kind of object that is also used often, so it works as a fixed phrase. It's the kind of phrase that in a language like English or German would tend to form a single-word compound. In Spanish *cepillo de dientes* forms a three-word [nominal phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase) that goes together as if it were a single noun, and you cannot change its parts (e.g. you cannot say *cepillo de los dientes* or *cepillo para dientes*; it would be understood but sounds very odd). You also have *pasta de dientes* ("toothpaste"), which is also a fixed phrase, and these two in a way reinforce each other.

The thing one uses for brushing one's hair is called *cepillo* alone in most cases, just as the thing one uses for brushing clothes or fabric or the fur of one's pet. *Cepillo* is a very general term and it covers all that. You add a specifier like *de la ropa* or *para el pelo* only when the context doesn't make it clear, and these specifiers work like normal Spanish phrases: you can change them a bit, since they don't form fixed phrases.

In the end there's no reason, as such, why some expressions are fixed in a way and not in another, and some other expressions are freer; you just have to learn them as they come.

Comment: I was about to say the same about pets. However, it's true it's still weird. Shall we think it's just "for lazyness"? Adding an "l" (de→del) makes no difference in no. os syllables, but adding "los" does.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike English, the use of articles or prepositions in Spanish do not bear any resemblance — it may in some cases, but this is not a rule; we do, nevertheless, use set phrases when it comes to article or preposition placing.

As stated by Pablo's answer, you'll have to learn these set expressions as part of phrases; although, if it's of any consolation, this is the same problem with which we, as non-native speakers, have to deal as part of our English language learning.

Comment: The Spanish nouns with de signal a noun in English or an adjective, which are closely linked in function. I really do not understand why my answer was downvoted. I guess people are not interested in the actual mechanisms of the two languages.

Answer (score 1):

- cepillo de dientes, toothbrush,
- cuarto de baño, bathroom
- casa de playa, beach house
- cuarto de invitados (dormitorio), guest room

If you use 'de', it means what comes after it is specifically connected to the function of the noun, as opposed to 'del' or 'de la'. It is connected to a specific quality of the noun.

If you say **mi casa de playa**, you mean your beach house, which is not a casa de la playa, which **would  imply** the beach has a house.

For example: **la ropa de la chica**, **the clothes that belong to the girl** (some girl, in a conversation); whereas **ropa de chica**, **girls' clothes**, as opposed to boys' clothes.

This is just an explanation for a beginner.

Comment: [correction; Why does X belong to Y?] A hairbrush is a cepillo **de** pelo. https://www.kissbel.es/blog/cepillo-de-pelo/ And not del pelo. Are you not interested in the underlying logic that I explained? cepillo de dientes, también. not: de los dientes or del diente.

Comment: Using site:.es (for Spanish from Spain), cepillo **de** pelo gets: About 380,000 results (0.55 seconds) // cepillo **del** pelo gets: About 17,800 results (0.42 seconds). Y la razón lingüística está en mi respuesta.

Comment: A few other countries, like **Colombia**: site:.co cepillo **de** pelo: About 66,200 results (0.61 seconds); cepillo **del** pelo: About 2,490 results (0.62 seconds) and **Argentina** (site:.ar), cepillo **de** pelo: About 71,100 results (0.59 seconds); cepillo del pelo: bout 4,710 results (0.53 seconds

Comment: Según las estatísticas arriba, sí. Pero no está bien. Y por eso hay muchíssimo más **de** y no **del**. Ocorrencias en si no explican nada. cepillo del pelo, entonces, con la misma lógica: cepillo del suelo. Y claro "cepillo del suelo", no va, sería cepillo **de** suelo; cepillo **de** uñas, etc. Porque los cepillos no hacen parte del pelo, ni del suelo ni de las uñas.